# What is a good way to put CyberBullying into an Etymology Paper?

Tags: etymology

I am doing an etymology paper and research paper on cyberbullying.
Etymology is a new word I neve hear of before. I am in for a surprise. (Been out of school for a while now) and have not taken English class in a while.

Any resources, help to type this paper would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ***cyber-*** is a "productive" prefix (we can visit cyberspace, have cybersex, send cybernauts into space,...). So a ***cyberbully*** is just a bully who plies his trade online rather than in the school playground. But I don't understand what "resources" you're looking for to write an "etymology" paper about this particular (regularly-formed) neologism.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure if you are aware of [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=cyber%2C+bullying), but it is usually the first stop when looking up etymology.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this! and No, I am not aware of this site, but I will look into it!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.